# Dump memory in lldb

Tags: gdb, dump, lldb

As stated on this [site.](http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html) When I want to dump memory in gdb.

The start point is `0x1000` and end `0x2000`.

For lldb start is `0x1000` and end `0x1200` .

Is there a reason for this or is just a mistake ?

---

Main question is:  How do I dump a memory area from `0x1000` to `0x2000` in lldb?

Comment: doesn't seem to be SO question

Comment: @tristan Ok then how to dump memory from 0x1000 to 0x2000 with lldb

Comment: NB: fixed the example on the lldb-gdb.html web page.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following works fine for me:

```
    (lldb) memory read --outfile /tmp/mem.txt 0x6080000fe680 0x6080000fe680+1000
```

Dumps 1000 bytes of memory, from the given start address, in hex format, to /tmp/mem.txt. Use --binary for binary format.

You could also use 'count' to state how many bytes you want to dump:

```
    (lldb) memory read --outfile /tmp/mem.txt --count 1000 0x6080000fe680
```

If you are in Xcode debugging environment and have a variable named 'note1', you can also use:

```
    (lldb) memory read --outfile /tmp/mem.bin note1 note1+100
```

Reads at the actual location 0x1000 fail in Xcode for me ("memory read failed"), must be protected in some way.

As to the difference between 0x1200 and 0x2000 in the documentation, I think it's simply a small mistake.

Comment: Also useful to note that you don't need to type the full lldb commands - only enough that it unambiguous. `memory read --outfile /tmp/mem.txt --count 1000 0x6080000fe680` can also be entered as `m r -o /tmp/mem.txt -c 1000 0x6080000fe680`. It's important to use the long form of the commands in examples for clarity, but I like to also demonstrate the shortest unique forms that people can use so they don't think they are required to type all of that on a day to day basis. Also, don't forget the gdb compat mem read cmds, e.g. `x/32gx $pc`, when talking about reading memory from the lldb cmd line.

Comment: binary format.  memory read --binary --outfile /tmp/bkey -c 162 0x165b35f4