# How to take a dump size more than 1024 using LLDB from iOS memory

Tags: ios, iphone, gdb, lldb

I am trying to get decrypted binary from my iPhone 5s memory which is x64-bit, I saw couple of tutorials about GDB but unfortunately i cannot use it because i am on arm7 device, i have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107733/dump-memory-in-lldb) but i get this errors:

```
(lldb) memory read --outfile /tmp/mem.bin --binary 0x1000 0x2000
error: Normally, 'memory read' will not read over 1024 bytes of data.
error: Please use --force to override this restriction just once.
error: or set target.max-memory-read-size if you will often need a larger limit.
```

When tried to use --force command i get this error:

```
(lldb) memory read --outfile /tmp/mem.bin --binary 0x1000 0x2000 --force
error: memory read failed for 0x1000
```

Then i tried to change the maximum read size but i got another error:

```
(lldb) set set max-memory-read-size 1000000
error: invalid value path 'max-memory-read-size'
(lldb) set append max-memory-read-size 1000000
error: invalid value path 'max-memory-read-size'
```

Is there any other way to do it, or maybe i am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`memory read` needs to have the `--force` option before the address range.  e.g.

```
(lldb) me r -o /tmp/outfile.bin -b --force $pc $pc+0x2000
8192 bytes written to '/tmp/outfile.bin'
(lldb)
```

The `max-memory-read-size` setting is under the `target` section so you need to qualify it:

```
(lldb) set set target.max-memory-read-size 0x2000
(lldb) me r -o /tmp/outfile.bin -b $pc $pc+0x2000
8192 bytes written to '/private/tmp/outfile.bin'
(lldb)
```

Comment: Hello Jason, thank you i was able to change the read size, but i got the same 2nd error, which says    `error: memory read failed for 0x2000`, another question about the ASLR is it the same as gdb = 0x2000?

Comment: On Mac OS X, lldb disables ASLR so the program will load at the same address every time (and the libraries, if they load in the same order, will also be at the same addresses).  This can make debugging a little easier if you know that something "interesting" happens at a given instruction address.  If you're debugging a 32-bit program on Mac/iOS, the first 4096 bytes are unreadable; if 64-bit, the first 4GB are unreadable.  It sounds like the memory you're trying to read at 0x1000-0x2000 is not mapped to any readable page in your process.

Comment: I'm debugging iphone 5s which is 64-bit device, ATM i'm testing a game process i need to get un-encrypted app executable so i can reverse it in IDA, how can i know if the app is 32 or 64, and if it's a 64-bit app which address should i start with?