# Examine arguments on stack with lldb

Tags: lldb

I am using `lldb` to trace through some plain C or C++ code (32 bit) that calls `CoreFoundation` functions such as `CFRunLoopTimerCreate`.

I've set a breakpoint on `CFRunLoopTimerCreate` and would like to examine the passed arguments.

How do I do that? `frame variable` is not working here (it prints nothing) as it's not in an ObjC context.

I guess I'll have to use the `x` command somehow to look at the memory above `sp` but whatever syntax I try, I keep getting error messages.

So, basically, what's the syntax for examining memory at an address a register points to? Also, is there a better way to look at arguments on the stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
(lldb) x $sp-10
0x7fff5cd3eda6: 00 00 86 0a ec 02 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0x7fff5cd3edb6: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 94 33 75 ff 7f  ............3u..
```

Registers are generally addressed as $rax etc.
You might also wish to check out this earlier question for some hints on shortening lldb memory read commands: [Dump memory in lldb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107733/dump-memory-in-lldb/21108966#21108966)

Comment: Ah! I kept addressing the register names the way they are shown, e.g. "esp" and "$esp", which didn't work. Never thought of trying just "sp" and "$sp".

Answer (score 4):

`x` is actually shorthand for the `memory read` command. You can choose the word size, e.g. this:

```
memory read --format x --size 4 --count 8 `$esp - 32`
```

Will show the top 32 bytes of the stack (on i386) formatted as 4-byte hexadecimal numbers. This might make it easier if you're looking for pointer values, etc. The argument to `--format` can also be `d` for decimal output. `--outfile` lets you specifiy a file path to which to write the memory contents, which may be more useful for large amounts. Surround expressions to evaluate with backticks `.

Comment: You write esp, but I am fairly sure I did try using "x $esp" and it did not work. Does it work only in the long form, perhaps? Confusing.

Comment: $esp doesn't work for me, either, regardless of short or long form. lldb version 340.4.70

Comment: $esp is the name of the stack pointer register on (32-bit) x86. You didn't specify what platform you're on, so if it's e.g. ARM then you'll need to use $sp/$r13.